# delphi download image without refresh the page

Tags: delphi, runtime, captcha

There is a webpage which includes an basic Captcha image, i solved captcha downloading image from website and using Tesaract. I'm using this function to show image in a Timage object without download;

```
FUNCTION DownloadImage(CONST URL : STRING ; ImageType : TGraphicClass = NIL) : TBitMap;
  VAR
    HTTP        : TIdHttp;
    S           : TStream;
    IMG         : TGraphic;
    STR         : AnsiString;
    LHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;

  BEGIN
    HTTP:=TIdHttp.Create(NIL);
    LHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
    TRY
      HTTP.IOHandler:=LHandler;
      S:=TMemoryStream.Create;
      TRY
        HTTP.Get(URL,S);
        IF NOT Assigned(ImageType) THEN BEGIN
          S.Position:=0;
          SetLength(STR,5);
          S.Read(STR[1],LENGTH(STR));
          IF COPY(STR,1,2)='BM' THEN
            ImageType:=TBitMap
          ELSE IF COPY(STR,1,3)='GIF' THEN
            ImageType:=TGIFImage
          ELSE IF COPY(STR,2,3)='PNG' THEN
            ImageType:=TPngImage
          ELSE IF (ORD(STR[1])=$FF) AND (ORD(STR[2])=$D8) THEN
            ImageType:=TJPEGImage
        END;
        IF NOT Assigned(ImageType) THEN RAISE EInvalidImage.Create('Unrecognized file format!');
        IMG:=ImageType.Create;
        TRY
          S.Position:=0;
          IMG.LoadFromStream(S);
          Result:=TBitMap.Create;
          TRY
            Result.Assign(IMG)
          EXCEPT
            Result.Free;
            RAISE
          END
        FINALLY
          IMG.Free
        END
      FINALLY
        S.Free
      END
    FINALLY
      HTTP.Free
    END
  END;
```

or for download image

```
function DownLoadInternetFile(Source, Dest : String): Boolean;
begin
  try
    Result := URLDownloadToFile(nil,PChar(Source),PChar(Dest),0,nil) = 0
  except
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

the problem is both of those functions connecting to web site to get image and because of this when i navigate the page with webbrowser on my form downloaded captcha picture and browsed page's captcha picture are different, the thing i i'm trying to do is get the picture from embeddedwb or webbrowser object directly when document complete, i also tryed to get screenshot of the webbrowser at runtime but i failed, the web page is :"https://esgm.sgk.gov.tr/Esgm/", thanks in advance.Sorry for bad English

Comment: The captcha is there to stop you doing what you are trying to do. It's only fair that if you defeat it, you do so with your own skills!

Comment: You're using the wrong approach to this problem. You first need to figure out how that Captcha works, then figure out how to defeat it. Hint: You never get the same image twice, the HTML for the page is always the same and the cookies are not changing on each refresh. It's 100% server-side, and that's it's weakness.

Answer (score 1):

If that is a TWebBrowser on your form, you might be able to modify that document. You can add a canvas to the document, draw the image onto the canvas, and then use canvas.toDataURL to get a base64 encoded representation of the image.

Something similar is done in this question, only in Javascript.
[Get image data in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript)

Which should result in something like this in Delphi.

```
function GetBase64Image(WebBrowser: TWebBrowser; ImageId: string): string;
var
  Document, Image, Canvas, Context: OleVariant;
begin
  Document := WebBrowser.Document;
  Image := Document.getElementById(ImageId);
  Canvas := Document.createElement('canvas');
  Canvas.Width := Image.Width;
  Canvas.Height := Image.Height;

  Context := Canvas.getContext('2d');
  Context.drawImage(Image, 0, 0);

  Result := Canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
  // Have to fix this. No time, sorry.
  //return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
end;
```

Comment: I haven't tried, but I think you will need IE 9 installed for this to work. TWebBrowser user IE and IE 8 doesn't support the HTML5 canvas.